# WinMain arguments

Tags: c++, parameters, arguments, argv

My issue is that the arguments are only retrieving the first letter in each of the parameters, for this i do not know why..
Could someone elaborate?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hpInstance, LPSTR nCmdLine, int iCmdShow){

LPWSTR *szArglist;
    int nArgs = 0;
    szArglist = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &nArgs);
    std::string a;
    for(int i=0; i<nArgs; i++){
        a += (LPCSTR)szArglist[i];
    }

    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCSTR)a.c_str(), (LPCSTR)a.c_str(), MB_OK);

    LocalFree(szArglist);
return 0;
}
```

I believe the issue lies within `CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &nArgs);`

Comment: This is exactly why C casts are evil. If you get a compiler error, don't instinctively throw in a cast. Use `std::wstring`, and the for loop could be replaced with initializing `a` to `GetCommandLineW` and removing the spaces.

Comment: To elaborate on why C casts are evil, a wide character might be represented by the bit sequence `0100000000000000` where the same bit sequence represented by ANSI characters is two characters `01000000 00000000`.  It's now a 1 character null-terminated string.

Comment: But then wstring would make my type a constant which would not be able to retrieve all of the array elements. The missing spaces are not a big  concern.

Comment: I under stand the bit sequencing now, but how can i get the arguments into an array?

Comment: `std::wstring` is no different from `std::string`. They're both typedefs that use different character types.

Comment: My question isn't about string and wstring...

Comment: I believe you can use std::wstring instead of std::string and LPCTSTR instead of LPCSTR.

Comment: Your *problem* (as far as I understand it, and assuming you have a good reason for not doing what I suggested in my answer, e.g. this is stub test code and you're going to do something interesting with the argument array) is that you are using `std::string` together with `LPCWSTR`, which won't work.  `LPCWSTR` goes with `std::wstring`, `LPCSTR` goes with `std::string`, and `LPCTSTR` should be avoided lest one go mad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LPWSTR` is typedefed to `wchar_t *`, `szArglist` is an array of `wchar_t *`s.  A wide character is 2 bytes instead of of 1, so a letter might be represented as:

0x0038 0x0000

However, if you take those bytes and say 'hey, pretend I'm a `char *`, this looks like a C-string with one letter (0x0038), because the 2nd char (0x0000) is null, which in C style strings represents the end of the string.

The problem you have is that you are trying to fit wide characters (`wchar_t`) into a non-wide (`char`) string, which is a much more complicated opperation.

The solution: either use wstring/wchar_t everywhere (corresponding to LPWSTR/LPCWSTR), or use string/char everywhere (corresponding to LPSTR and LPCSTR I believe). Note that your project setting for 'use unicode' should match your decision. Try not to mix these!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this just be

```
int WINAPI 
WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hpInstance, LPSTR nCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, nCmdLine, nCmdLine, MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
int WINAPI 
WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hpInstance, LPSTR nCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    MessageBoxW(NULL, GetCommandLineW(), GetCommandLineW(), MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

?

Comment: OH WOWWWW >.< .-. DUDE ILY.. i so didnt know you could all them directly! Your a boss.

Comment: By "them" you mean the A and W forms of MessageBox?  Yeah, just about every Windows API function that takes a string has both, and modern best coding practice is to use them all the time.  The unqualified versions are just for backward compatibility with old code.